# Incorporating neighboring years in multilevel model, estimated in Stan using brms

Tags: multilevel-analysis, stan, brms

I am estimating a multilevel model in Stan, using the brms package. Specifically, I am estimating a model of the following form:

```
m1 <- brm(y ~ 1 + (1 | year))
```

The model comes out quite nicely. What I would like to do is to explicitly incorporate information on neighboring years to add a little more information to the model. `year` is a character vector, running from 2009 to 2023. I would like to tell the model that 2009 neighbors on 2010, which neighbors on 2011, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could express your idea as there being classes of related years, where the same year is a member of multiple such classes (e.g. 2020 is a member of years adjacent to 2019, 2020 and 2021). With `brms` you'd use a multi-membership term to express this: `... + (1|mm(equiv_year1, equiv_year2, equiv_year3)`, where you would for each year populate the 3 variables with the year before, itself and the year after (order doesn't really matter).